# Open Website with window authentication with batch file or vbscript

Tags: asp.net, iis, vbscript, batch-file

I am trying to open a window authenticated page in the browser from a batch file.

My Situation is..

I have a website `http://mysite.com`

I created a folder under `Root` named `Folder`

I created an `aspx` page under that folder `file.aspx`.

I remove the `anonymous access` and add `window authentication` to the folder `Folder`

So, when I go to `http://mysite.com/Folder/file.aspx`, it will ask for window authentication.

Now I have a batch file.

I write this

`explorer http://mysite.com/Folder/file.aspx`

Then it will open `IE` and open the page. But I want to key in the `username` and `password`

in the `window authentication` dialog box.

Any idea how to do that?

Or is there any alternative way?

Can it be done in vbscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try automating ie with WatiN

http://watin.org/

Comment: I saw the method. That is written for C#. I want something like that in batch file. Can it be done?

Comment: yes. 2 ways: make small console apps that wrap watin, or better yet, use PowerShell to manipulate WatiN directly.